# How to find and replace from the cursor forward

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find and replace text starting at the cursor forward in the active file.  VS Code defaults to replacing EVERY occurrence in the entire document (when you select replace ALL).  How can I do this?

Comment: still trying to figure this out myself.